Annihilator basis after extension of scalars
Consider finitely dimensional associative algebra $A$ over field $\Bbbk$, an element $a\in A$ and the set $S_a=\{x\in A\vert ax=xa=0\}$.
Let $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ be the basis of $A$. Since $S$ is a subalgebra, $S$ has a finite basis $\{x_1,\dots, x_k\}$
Now let's take an algebraic closure of $\Bbbk$ and denote it by $\overline{\Bbbk}$. After extension of scalars $A\otimes_{\Bbbk}\overline{\Bbbk}$ has a basis $\{e_1\otimes 1,\dots,e_n\otimes 1\}$.
Does the set $\widehat{S}_a=\{x\in A\otimes_{\Bbbk}\overline{\Bbbk}\vert ax=xa=0\}$ has a basis $\{x_1\otimes 1,\dots, x_k\otimes 1\}$ or it can become bigger?

Hint: Show that $x \otimes y \in \hat{S}_a$ if and only if $x \in S_a$.

@Frank Thank you. I can prove it for $x\otimes y$. But in general an element $p$ in $A\otimes_{\Bbbk}\overline{\Bbbk}$ equals $e_1\otimes y_1 + \dots + e_n\otimes y_n$ i.e not decomposable. And I don't know how to solve it for indecomposable $p$.

Note that $S_a$ is the kernel of the map $a : A \to A \oplus A$ given
$$
x \mapsto (ax, xa).
$$
Thus, we have an exact sequence
$$
0 \to S_a \to A \xrightarrow{a} A \oplus A.
$$
By exactness of the tensor product with $\overline{\mathbb{k}}$ (in fact, left exactness is enough), we get an exact sequence
$$
0 \to S_a \otimes_\mathbb{k} \overline{\mathbb{k}} \to A \otimes_\mathbb{k} \overline{\mathbb{k}} \xrightarrow{a \otimes \mathrm{id}} (A \oplus A) \otimes_\mathbb{k} \overline{\mathbb{k}}.
$$
Now, under the natural isomorphism $(A \oplus A) \otimes_\mathbb{k} \overline{\mathbb{k}} \cong (A \otimes_\mathbb{k} \overline{\mathbb{k}}) \oplus (A \otimes_\mathbb{k} \overline{\mathbb{k}})$, we see that $a \otimes \mathrm{id}$ is again the map
$$
x \mapsto (ax, xa),
$$
where $x$ is now an element of $A \otimes_\mathbb{k} \overline{\mathbb{k}}$. So by definition, we have $S_a \otimes_\mathbb{k} \overline{\mathbb{k}} = \hat{S}_a$. Therefore, if $\{x_1, \dots, x_k\}$ is a basis of $S_a$, then $\{x_1 \otimes 1, \dots, x_k \otimes 1\}$ is a basis of $\hat{S}_a$.

Do you think it is possible to prove an inverse statement? That the set $\overline{S}_a$ with $a\in A\otimes_k \overline{\Bbbk}$ is of the form $S\otimes\overline{\Bbbk}$ for some $S\subset A$?
